# Microsoft SQL query two largest capital

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the instruction:

Display the two largest capital and their corresponding company names in the `DocStatus` table.

Here's the table `DocStatus`:

```
DocID    Company                    Capital
2001     Teewai.com Inc.            250000.00
2002     Fave Company               250000.00
2003     Goldilocks Bakeshop Corp   500000.00
2004     Collegian Exponent Inc.    100000.00
2005     Uniphil Computer Inc.      250000.00
```

**Question:**

What's the correct query for this? Thank you.

(*500000 and 250000 are the top two but 3 companies have the same capital of 250000*)

Comment: Did my answer get what you are looking for? If yes, feel free to accept the answer. Else, let me know if you need any modification.

Answer (score 4):

If you need only the topmost 2 records then try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM DocStatus
ORDER BY Capital DESC,Company
```

It will sort the result in descending order of Capital. And if multiple records have same Capital, it will sort them in the ascending order of Company Name. And finally, selects the top 2 records.

The result will be:

```
DOCID   COMPANY                     CAPITAL
2003    Goldilocks Bakeshop Corp    500000
2002    Fave Company                250000
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4522/1)

**OR**

If you want the companies which have the 1st and 2nd highest capital, use this:

```
SELECT TOP(2) WITH TIES * FROM DocStatus
ORDER BY Capital DESC
```

The beauty of this clause is that it can be used with the `WITH TIES` clause to retrieve all similar rows to a base result set.

The result will be:

```
DOCID   COMPANY                     CAPITAL
2003    Goldilocks Bakeshop Corp    500000
2001    Teewai.com Inc.             250000
2002    Fave Company                250000
2005    Uniphil Computer Inc.       250000
```

Read more [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

Comment: no good ! in case of `ties` top(n)` will not give required results ! you need to use `with ties` to get top N results!

Answer (score 2):

try this !

```
select top(2) with ties * from table order by Capital desc
```

<kbd>[SEE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4522/2)</kbd>